# How can i install netCDF4?

Tags: terminal, installation, netcdf4

I tried the script here: https://gist.github.com/perrette/cd815d03830b53e24c82?fbclid=IwAR2loEbaawG9iOUd3yq3mFUUBUTHKLUJfTdU18umq9cJDF-fIlQqQ2PxATA

Then I downloaded hdf5-1.10.5 and netcdf-4.6.1 and stored on desktop. When I opened the terminal with the directory Desktop/hdf5-1.10.5 and ran this command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-hl make sudo make install
```

I received this error :

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-hl
configure: netCDF 4.6.1
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `make': machine `make' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub make failed
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would help if you added more details about your platform and  expected results.

Comment: Sry but what kind of details can i give to you for you help me? i don't understand how can i install this but i need it for a university work. The professor told me to install this and the objective is to apply a modeling data method and plot the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install netCDF4 for python, you can do so from the command line using `pip install netCDF4`, it automatically takes care of any other dependencies such as the C libraries. If you mean another platform, you are going to need to specify which.